# Get the permissions of an Active Directory schema object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

- PS Version: PowerShell 7+
- OS Version: Windows Server 2016

**Objective:** I would like to use PowerShell to get the permissions of an AD schema object without the need of the Active Directory PsDrive / PsProvider.

The Active Directory PsProvider that comes with the AD Module does not work with PowerShell 7+ on Windows Server 2016 from my testing. [This MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/module-compatibility?view=powershell-7.1) also touches on that. Because that PsProvider is needed to create/use an Active Directory PsDrive, you can't access AD objects like this `AD:\`. Using this method is typically what I prefer. Below is an example of exactly what I need except I'm using Windows PowerShell and not PowerShell 7+.

This gets the configuration schema permissions:

```
(Get-Acl "AD:$((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext)").Access
```

An example of the distinguished name for that object:

```
CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
```

With the limitations outlined, what other options within PowerShell 7+ can I use to access those permissions?

Answer (score 0):

•   According to the command that you have run on powershell in Windows Server 2016, it displays the active directory schema permissions of the concerned domain. But when running this command in my environment with Powershell 7.0+ installed as you can see in the image below, I got the same appropriate output as in normal powershell.

[image: AD Schema permission]

•   Though you can change the permissions relating to schema objects by using the query as given below: -

Add ACL rule for the right "Read-write all properties/this object and all descendants" –

```
 $rootdse = Get-ADRootDSE
 $extendedrightsmap = @{}
 Get-ADObject -SearchBase ($rootdse.ConfigurationNamingContext) -LDAPFilter `
 "(&(objectclass=controlAccessRight)(rightsguid=*))" -Properties 
  displayName,rightsGuid | 
 % {$extendedrightsmap[$_.displayName]=[System.GUID]$_.rightsGuid}
 $extendedrightsmap
```

Please find the below link for more information: -

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51121.active-directory-schema-update-and-custom-attribute.aspx

Comment: You're on a Windows 10 machine. According to the link I provided, the ActiveDirectory module is fully supported with PowerShell 7+ on Windows Server 1809+ (Windows Server 2019) and Windows 10 1809+ as long as you have RSAT installed.

Comment: After reviewing your initial code, it doesn't appear that your example is getting the information I'm looking for. I'm looking to get the permissions on this object `"AD:$((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext)"`. In case I'm not using the correct terminology here, I need the equivalent output of the command I provided in my OP. That's not to be confused with needing the exact same object type being returned from Get-Acl. Maybe "Access" is the correct term here.

Comment: To inform you, I have posted the screenshot above from a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter edition VM. Have installed Powershell 7.0+ externally on it, added the roles of AD and DNS, then have run the command which displays the permissions on that particular AD container. To ensure this, you can check the same in ADSI.edit through GUI mode.

Comment: Thanks for updating me with your environment specs. Your testing environment is on the compatibility list according to the link I provided. That explains why you're able to get it the results you're getting. As mentioned in my initial, the issue I'm getting is happening on  Windows Server 2016 which is not on the compatibility list.

Comment: In case my point wasn't understood previously, the code you provided does not produce the results I'm looking for. Further more, you're running test on a completely different test environment than where I'm experiencing the issue of the topic. I cannot accept your answer in it's current state